# Increasing function definition.

Tags: real-analysis

1$$
x_1 < x_2 \quad\Rightarrow\quad f(x_1) \le f(x_2).   
$$
2$$
x_1  \le x_2 \quad\Rightarrow\quad f(x_1) \le f(x_2).
$$what's the difference between  definition 1 and 2.?
I think they are equivalents ,but I don't know why?
the case of $x_1 = x_2$ is always true . so what's the point of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, $2.$ implies $1.$ (as $x<y \implies x\le y$).

If $1.$ is true, if $x_1\le x_2 $ then
either $x_1 < x_2$ and you can apply $1.$, or $x_1 = x_2$ and $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. So this is an equivalence.

Comment: if $2.$ and $x<y$, you also have $x\le y$. So no, I mean $2.\implies 1.$

Comment: ah, yes correct :)

Comment: @mookid if we have a strict inequality in the left side,we say that f is monotonically increasing ?

Comment: no, it is needed on the RHS! (and you *need* the first formulation in this case)

Comment: because is is false: if $x=y$ you don't have $f(x) < f(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are the same. The second one implies the first one. Just note that in case $x_1 = x_2$ the implication is trivially true.